# Frase acerca de tempo da recompensa não traduzida no site

Tags: suporte, tradução

Ofereci uma recompensa pela primeira vez e acabou o tempo sem que eu atribuísse a mesma a algum usuário.

Nesse cenário foi exibida a seguinte frase em inglês:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Tradução sugerida em https://pt.traducir.win/string/1005

```
Você tem $timeLeft$ para conceder a recompensa
```